# Line break in right hand side of alignat

Tags: line-breaking, alignat

I am trying to build an equation like the one in the image, where one of the lines at the right-hand-side has a line-break. I tried to do this by putting it in its own extra equation, but as can be seen in the image, this produces a lot of extra spacing and an extra equation reference.

[image]

The image was generated using

```
\begin{subequations}
  \label{eq:class:sub}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \text{min}\quad & \sum_{i \in V} e_i - \sum_{i \in V} y_ia_i - u \\
    \text{s.t.}\quad
    & a_i \leq e_i + p_{\lambda_i} && \qquad\text{for \(i \in V\)} \\
    & a_n + a_m \leq 1+\sum_{i \in S} a_i && \qquad\text{for \(a,b \in V\) and \(S
    \subseteq V\)} \\
    &&&\qquad\text{separating \(a\) from \(b\)} \\
    & a_i \in \{0,1\} && \qquad\text{for \(i \in V\)}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

How can I move the "separating a from b" part further up so it fits together with the text that comes before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{19} % just to reproduce the picture

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:class:sub}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \min\quad & \sum_{i \in V} e_i - \sum_{i \in V} y_ia_i - u \\
  \text{s.t.}\quad
    & a_i \leq e_i + p_{\lambda_i} && \qquad\text{for \(i \in V\)} \\
    & a_n + a_m \leq 1+\sum_{i \in S} a_i && \qquad
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      for \(a,b \in V\) and \(S\subseteq V\) \\
      separating \(a\) from \(b\)
      \end{tabular} \\
    & a_i \in \{0,1\} && \qquad\text{for \(i \in V\)}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this answer because it is the simplest way to do it starting from my original code, but the other answers are good too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for the dedicated package, `optidef`, namely its `mini!` environment,with the help of `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

    \begin{mini!}[2]
        {}{\sum_{i \in V} e_i - \sum_{i \in V} y_ia_i - u \label{eq:1a}}
        {\label{eq:1}}{}
        \addConstraint{a_i \leq e_i + p_{\lambda_i}}{\label{eq:1b}}{\text{for }i \in V}
        \addConstraint{a_n + a_m \leq 1+\sum_{i \in S} a_i}{\qquad\label{eq:1c}}{\Shortunderstack[l]{for \(a,b \in V \) and \(S \subseteq V\)\\separating \(a\) from \(b\)}}
        \addConstraint{ a_i \in \{0,1\} }{\label{eq:1d}}{\text{for }i \in V}
   \end{mini!}
We can see from \cref{eq:1}, and more precisely from \cref{eq:1a,eq:1b,eq:1c} blah blah. 

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing that I could use the `\Shortunderstack` command without also switching to the `optidef` package?

Comment: Yes, it is independent from `optidef` since it's defined in  `stackengine`.  For me, optidef in optimisation equations has the advantage of a simpler syntax (all the complicated job is done by the package in the background).

Answer (score 2):

There must be several ways to accomplish your typesetting goal. One method I can think of is to place the text for both lines into a `\parbox` of suitably-chosen width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\mylen
% measure width of \parbox below:
\settowidth\mylen{for \(a,b \in V\) and \(S\subseteq V\)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{19} % just for this example
\begin{subequations}
  \label{eq:class:sub}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \min\quad & \sum_{i \in V} e_i - \sum_{i \in V} y_ia_i - u \\
    \text{s.t.}\quad
    & a_i \leq e_i + p_{\lambda_i} 
        &\qquad&\text{for \(i \in V\)} \\
    & a_n + a_m \leq 1+\sum_{i \in S} a_i 
        &&\parbox[t]{\mylen}{for \(a,b \in V\) and \(S\subseteq V\) 
                             separating \(a\) from \(b\)} \\[1ex]
    & a_i \in \{0,1\} 
        &&\text{for \(i \in V\)}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```